# Creating a label inside of a child window with Tkinter

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, label

I don't know why this is happening but I'm trying to create an "Options" child window with Tkinter from a MenuBar. The child window pops up but when I try to create a label within the child window, the label appears on the main window... I don't know why this is happening. I have been searching the internet for a while and can't find an answer to my problem. Here is the code.

```
class slot(Frame):
def __init__(self):
    self.root = Frame.__init__(self)
    # Set up the main window and the variables 
    self.master.title("Slot Machine")
    # Open in full screen
    self.w, self.h = self.master.winfo_screenwidth(), self.master.winfo_screenheight()
    self.master.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.w, self.h))
    # Add the drop down menu
    menubar = Menu(self.master)
    self.master.config(menu=menubar)
    fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
    fileMenu.add_command(
        label="New Game", 
        command=self.__init__,
        underline = 0
    )
    fileMenu.add_command(
        label="Options", 
        command=self.newStartingValue,
        underline = 0
    )
    fileMenu.add_command(
        label="Exit", 
        command=self.quit,
        underline = 0
    )
    fileMenu.add_separator()
    menubar.add_cascade(
        label = "File", 
        menu = fileMenu, 
        underline = 0
    )
    helpMenu = Menu(menubar)
    helpMenu.add_command(
        label="About...", 
        command=self.showHelp,
        underline = 0
    )
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu = helpMenu, underline = 0)
    # Manage the main window and center everything
    self.grid(sticky = W+E+N+S)
    self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    for i in xrange(4):
        self.rowconfigure(i, weight = 1)
    for i in xrange(3):
        self.columnconfigure(i, weight = 1)

def showHelp(self):
    showinfo("About", "The One Armed Bandit is a simplistic slot machine game")
def newStartingValue(self):
    self._optionsPanel = Toplevel(self.root)
    self._optionsPanel.title("Options")
    self._optionsPanel.grid()
    self._optionsPanelLabel = Label(self, text = "New Pot Starting Value").pack()
    self._optionsPanelLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

I tried to only show necessary details. I think this should help you to figure it out. If not I can paste all code if needed.
I can not understand why the label is not being put into the self._optionsPanel object.

Comment: This is at once way too much code (do we really need to see all of the menu items on all of the menus) and not nearly enough (it's not runnable as-is, and it's impossible to guess what needs to be added to _make_ it runnable). Please see [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for guidance on what's useful.

Comment: @abarnert how is it too much but not nearly enough???? Yeah it doesn't run because it is partial. I said that in the top. All I wanted to know was how to create a label inside of that child window... I can put all the code there in order to make it run... But you won't get less code. I don't know, I honestly feel as if you didn't read the whole details to the question. And the code should run just fine if you ran slot().mainloop() All it should create with that code is a window with a menu bar and the command I want to evaluate is options.

Comment: What part of your question do you think I didn't read? Meanwhile, if you read my comment it explains exactly how it's too much code and not enough. I can try to re-word it a bit: you "tried to only show necessary details", but you included a ton of unnecessary details (like the `About…` menu item and the code it runs), and left out some necessary details (if it's easy to make the program runnable by adding one line, then add the one line, don't force us to guess what needs to be added). Again, follow the link; it will explain much better than I can in an SO comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following line, the code creates Label widget inside `self` (which is the frame inside the main window).

```
self._optionsPanelLabel = Label(self, text = "New Pot Starting Value").pack()
```

Replace it with (set new toplevel as its parent):

```
self._optionsPanelLabel = Label(self._optionsPanel, text = "New Pot Starting Value").pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three problems in the last two lines of code:

```
self._optionsPanelLabel = Label(self, text = "New Pot Starting Value").pack()
self._optionsPanelLabel.grid(row=0,column=1)
```

First, you're passing `self` as the parent to `Label`. If you want it to appear on `self._optionsPanel`, you have to pass *that* as the parent.

Second, `pack` returns `None`, so `self._optionsPanelLabel` will be `None`, so the attempt to call `grid` will print an exception traceback to `stderr` and exit the function immediately. I'm willing to bet you've made that same mistake multiple other times in your code, so you probably have all kinds of things hooked up wrong.

Third, you can't call `pack` and `grid` on the same widget. Or, rather, you can, but once you do, the `pack` is undone. (And this breaks any other widgets `pack`ed in the same container, so calling both `pack` and `grid` on multiple widgets is an even bigger problem.)

Comment: you can call pack and grid on the same object, it just doesn't do what you think it will do. If you call pack and then grid, pack will effectively be ignored, and visa versa. What you definitely can't do is use pack on one widget and grid on another, when the two share the same parent.